# MySQL Administrator GUI tool for 5.6

Tags: mysql, browser, administrator, workbench

I have searched for this tool for version 5.6, but unable to find it. Instead MySQL Workbench shows up. I am guessing that MySQL Administrator GUI tool and MySQL Query Browser GUI tool merged in MySQL Workbench? Can someone confirm or give the detail? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed, that is [what happened](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Workbench#MySQL_GUI_Tools_Bundle).